# Automatically Login using session id stored in cookie

Tags: php, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

Since **php login application** uses **session id**(one for each user) which is stored in **cookie** which is send as header information to server that allows the user to get automatically logged in(assuming that the user is already logged in some another tab in same browser lets say Chrome).

My question is **if I store that user session id cookie information in another browser**(lets say Firefox) **and open the same application, will the user will get automatically logged in or not.**

Or if someone finds out my session id and store them in its browser will the application will allow the user to login or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack).

If somebody steals your session cookie, **and** you are still logged into the website, then yes. The attacker can log in using that session cookie.

Answer (score 1):

And because of the answer given by @JonTan, you may see the fact that auto-login based only on PHP's session ID is not secure.

There all sort of solutions to that problem, but the base of each of them is to try and identify as many "unique" attributes of the user.

For example, store the user user-agent and ip address. When you "auto-login" the user, check for those details as well, and if they don't match than destroy the session. You may also add another token that you generate from this data as an "extra" security attribute and store it in the cookie, and check if that token match as well (you will most likely want to generate this token based on the user-agent, ip etc, so that you will be able to regnerate the token to match).